# JavaFX: bind TableView column with number of rows of another TableView

Tags: tableview, javafx-8

I have a `TableView` of `Roads` with a column `Name` and a column `Number of Lanes`. `Number of Lanes` show a integer that is the number of lanes of a road. When add a new road, I have another `TableView` where set the properties for a lane. My `Lane` class is:

```
public class Lane {

    private StringProperty name;

    private FloatProperty width;

    private BooleanProperty normalDirection;

    public Lane(String name, float width, boolean normalDirection) {
        this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
        this.width = new SimpleFloatProperty(width);
        this.normalDirection = new SimpleBooleanProperty(normalDirection);
    }

    public void setName(String value) { 
        nameProperty().set(value); 
    }

    public String getName() { 
        return nameProperty().get();
    }

    public StringProperty nameProperty() { 
        if (name == null) {
            name = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "name");
        }
        return name; 
    }

    public void setWidth(float value) { 
        widthProperty().set(value); 
    }

    public float getWidth() { 
        return widthProperty().get();
    }

    public FloatProperty widthProperty() { 
        if (width == null) {
            width = new SimpleFloatProperty(this, "width");
        }
        return width; 
    }

    public void setNormalDirection(boolean value) { 
        normalDirectionProperty().set(value);
    }

    public boolean getNormalDirection() { 
        return normalDirectionProperty().get();
    }

    public BooleanProperty normalDirectionProperty() { 
        if (normalDirection == null) normalDirection = new SimpleBooleanProperty(this, "normalDirection");
        return normalDirection; 
    } 
}
```

I'm trying to create a class `Road` where I would like to bind a property `private IntegerProperty numberOfLanes` with the size of the `ObservableList<Lane>` used in the `TableView` of lanes, but I don't know what's the best way to do it.

I'm newbie of `JavaFX` world and any help is appreciated. Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like:

```
public class Road {
   private final ObservableList<Lane> lanes = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
   public final ObservableList<Lane> getLanes() {
      return lanes ;
   }

   private final ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper numberOfLanes = new ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper(this, "numberOfLanes");
   public final int getNumberOfLanes() {
      return numberOfLanes.get();
   }
   public ReadOnlyIntegerProperty numberOfLanesProperty() {
      return numberOfLanes.getReadOnlyProperty();
   }

   public Road() {
      numberOfLanes.bind(Bindings.size(lanes));
   }
}
```